# Defining uint="unsigned int" is not being applied as I expected using nvcc in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, cuda, nvcc

Sorry, stuck with VS2013 but I don't think that is a problem.  The same code compiles correctly on linux.  I assume I need to define uint rather than edit 100+ lines of code.
I am getting "error : explicit type is missing ("int" assumed)" on first line of below code

```
__device__ uint inline get_smid(void)
{
  uint ret;
  asm("mov.u32 %0, %%smid ;" : "=r"(ret) );
  return ret; 
}
```

At the property for the app there is only CUDA => Host => Preprocessor Definitions I put in

```
WIN32;uint="unsigned int"
```

This seemed to fix the "assumed int" but now I am getting "error : expected a declaration"
Replacing uint with unsigned int in the source will compile without error.  There is a lot of uint and this breaks with the linux build.  Is more required besides 'uint="unsigned int"'?  Maybe a switch to cause the NVCC to accept the uint and not give an error?

Just discovered a lot of ushort and I am guessing the same problem.  Also, looking at the Linux build, the source were compiled with gcc but the link was done with nvcc so there is a difference.

====sample CUDA has ushort====
i must have not set up the include correctly as these variables are probably ok to use.

Comment: What is wrong with old fashioned `typedef unsigned int uint;`, or simple `#define uint unsigned int`?

Comment: Nothing wrong with that.  The folks who maintain the Linux version of the code will simple remove it.  Hopefully they will remove it after I have built my windows version.

Answer (score 1):

I gave up trying to define uint or ushort as the sample CUDA programs had

```
typedef unsigned int uint;
typedef unsigned short ushort;
```

so I just put those in each cu file that needed it.